Docker Container nested repository issue
I'm learning Docker and my project have such docker config as follows:

When I run following command in terminal
docker-compose build && docker compose up

It's creating Docker image & run that Image.
Now, Docker Desktop --> Docker container showing nested directory as follows:
    essential_command      (Repository Name)
       essential_command    (Docker Container Name)


But, I want to show only Docker Image only, not Repos name as follows:


When I build the docker image directly through command docker build -t essential-command ., it's generating as expected.

But how to do that through conpose.yaml ? 
Is there any way to do that ?

The directory you're seeing is a Docker Compose project.
I do think you can run services from Docker Compose without them being under a specific project, as that is how compose controls its stack

yes, when I build the docker image directly through command it's generating as expected. docker build -t essential-command . But how to do that through conpose.yaml ?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  It looks like you've included several key files like the Dockerfile and the package.json only rendered into an image, and then with a hard-to-read dark-on-black color scheme.  Can you [edit] the question to replace as many of the images as you can with plain text?

It looks like your question might be about Docker Desktop's presentation of containers launched via Compose.  Docker proper has no such thing as "nesting" or "directories"; CLI tools like docker run, docker ps, or docker images won't show any sort of container objects.
